# C# Modular way to wrap a null-check around x code

Tags: c#, linq, null

I have a function that returns either an open Form or null if it hasn't been opened yet.

- If the form *is* open I want to perform an operation (like refreshing it's list).
- If it *is not* open, and the function returns null, I don't want to do anything.

What is a modular way to wrap this functionality without copy-pasting the same code?

Current Code:

```
private void Sample()
{
    var desiredForm = MasterForm.FindForm<FormType1>();
    if (desiredForm != null)
        desiredForm.DoAction1();

    var otherForm = MasterForm.FindForm<FormType2>();
    if (otherForm != null)
        otherForm.DoAction1(someParam);

}
```

Desired Code:

```
private void Sample()
{
    MasterForm.FindForm<FormType1>().DoAction1();
    MasterForm.FindForm<FormType2>().DoAction1(someParam);
}
```

But I'm not sure how to get around the check for nulls. Any other shorthand for this would help too.

Failed Attempt:

```
private void Sample()
{
    // initialization of the new forms would fail because they lack all parameters
    (MasterForm.FindForm<FormType1>() ?? new FormType1()).DoAction1();
    (MasterForm.FindForm<FormType2>() ?? new FormType2()).DoAction1(someParam);
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using C# 6 you should be able to do this:

```
private void Sample()
{
    // initialization of the new forms would fail because they lack all parameters
    MasterForm.FindForm<FormType1>()?.DoAction1();
    MasterForm.FindForm<FormType2>()?.DoAction1(someParam);
}
```

Its (`?.`) called the "null-conditional" operator, see the docs [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/null-conditional-operators)

Comment: Other than the use of `?.` operator ... this is less efficient cause you are calling the same method `MasterForm.FindForm<FormType>()` twice unnecessarily

Comment: OP is checking two different types, two different calls are needed.

Answer (score 0):

A normal `if` condition would do as well other than the shorthand `null-conditional` operator (as in other answer) but yes more typing...

```
private void Sample()
{
    var result = MasterForm.FindForm<FormType>();
    if(result != null)
    {
     result.DoAction1();
     result.DoAction1(someParam);
    }
}
```

Comment: Is this not exactly what the OP posted as "Current Code"?

Comment: @maccettura it only does one call to `MasterForm.FindForm<FormType>();`, but if it where me I would have combined both your answers, do one call like this one then do `result?.DoAction1(); 
 result?.DoAction1(someParam);`

Comment: @maccettura, not exactly and better then posted code cause OP unnecessarily calling the same method twice and having two if condition which can be reduced and so the answers shows

Comment: I've clarified in the sample code that it's two different types of forms, sorry for the confusion. I know I could simply reference the local variable instead of calling the function twice. Thanks for the answer about null-conditionals though.